# How do I have one address field in django?

Tags: python, django, reactjs, autocomplete

I have shopping app that lists stores by address. Currently, user address is 5 fields: building number and street name, city, state, zip code and county.

I’d like now to have one address field in the front end to be able to add auto complete feature. But store the address in the fields above.

I am using react.js for front end.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add something like googlemap api for your autocomplate field like shown in this example.
[search box autocomplate from google map api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox)